# Bitnami Jasperserver Error 500 (it takes longer than 60 seconds)

Tags: java, oracle, jasper-reports, timeout, jasperserver

Good afternoon, I have a Bitnami virtual machine with JasperServer
5.6.0, with a report that connects to Oracle.

The query report, accessed using fixed parameters in a dbms as
DbVisualizer takes about 6/7 seconds, but Jasper takes more than 60
seconds, causing a 500 error.

As additional data in a JasperServer installed on windows, it takes
about 2 minutes consultation, but no errors.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Errors that I get are:

**In the jasperserver site**

> HTML response error code: 500, error
>
> HTML response was:
>
> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform
> them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed
> just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.

**In IReport**

> ; nested exception is: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1;
> columnNumber: 50; Blank spaces are necessary between publicId and
> systemId.  AxisFault 
>  faultSubcode:
>
> faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; Blank spaces are necessary between publicId and
> systemId. 
>  faultActor:    faultNode:    faultDetail:....

**In the tomcat log**

> [Wed Mar 11 08:44:53.797515 2015] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 3471]
> (70007)The timeout specified has expired: AH01030: ajp_ilink_receive()
> can't receive header [Wed Mar 11 08:44:54.341386 2015]
>
> [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 3471] [client 10.1.1.209:49888] AH00992:
> ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed

Comment: @AlvaroDevotto. Could you please show your code?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms  The code of the report is available at: http://pastebin.com/cw3aY0rt

Comment: That's too much code. Can you create small sample code that causes the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms  The report only shows the query result, query is http://pastebin.com/YtJ0Dts6

Comment: Is the timeout occurring on your server or on someone else's server?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms On my server. In my bitnami virtual machine, these errors occur, in my windows server runs smoothly, but it takes about 2 minutes. For that much difference with the 6 seconds of DbVisualizer?

Comment: If you can create a small easily-shared example program that gives you the same errors, then we can probably help you figure it out. However, it would probably take me several days to figure it out with what information you have given us so far. Please read and do the steps mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you cannot do that, then we may not be able to help you.